# If a company is in debt, do employees with equity have any financial obligation?

Tags: startup, equity

If I choose to work for salary + equity, and the company loses and/or is in debt, am I obligated to pay a part of the company debts?

Is it common in the startup world?

Comment: Might need to ask this in the Law S.E. as it is not about the main goal of this stack: navigating the workplace.  What kind of company is it anyway, is it a limited liabilty?

Comment: It's common for startups to fall to pieces

Comment: @solarflare: or Money.SE since the question pretty much boils down to a stockholder's obligations.

Comment: Seconding advice to take it to Money or Law, but in either place probably the first question they'll ask you is "is your company a LLC?"

Comment: It will depend both on how the company is structured (partnership, limited liability corporation) and on local laws. Even if it were not off topic it would need a lot more information for a useful answer.

Comment: I'm seconding @PatriciaShanahan. An useful answer will depend on your location and what type of legal entity it is (according to your location) - please seek legal advice from a qualified person

Answer (score 8):

Generally, **no, equity-investors risk only the capital they contribute.** If a company is liquidated or restructured, the debt-holders have first claim on assets. You, as an equity-holder, may only make claims on assets after the debt-holders are made whole.

---

However, what I say above is a simplification and not true of all corporate structures. Some common exceptions to be mindful of:

- In a **sole proprietorship**, your personal assets are at risk if the firm’s liabilities exceed firm assets.
- In **partnerships**, the personal assets of *general partners* are at risk if the firm’s liabilities exceed firm assets. This is not true for *limited partners.*
- Individuals may file **civil suits** to reclaim losses from your personal assets.

---

As an additional aside, you’ll likely not receive equity compensation - instead, **you’ll receive options.**  In the most common form, these options enable you to buy equity from the firm at a pre-determined price at a time in the future, specifically after an IPO.  Options lack the obligations and rights of equity, but have a similar financial behavior - and thus are a favored way of providing equity-like compensation to employees of new ventures.

Comment: *" If a company is liquidated or restructured, the debt-holders have first claim on assets..."* - The new trend is to protect institutional investors and push the risk on regular shareholders, ordinary investors and depositors. See, for example, [Cypriots challenge "bail-in" to fight for lost savings](https://www.reuters.com/article/cyprus-bank-depositors-idUSL6N0G232Y20130806). That kind of perversion will likely spread to all verticals.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to setup an entity such that employees with equity can wind up with financial obligations if the company goes bankrupt. But I've never heard of anyone setting up a company in this way and it would seem to be an incredibly foolish thing to do.

Comment: Well, I guess a ponzi scheme does this, where you pay the company to "work" for them... but obviously that's pretty bad and you don't want to do this.

Comment: Nelson: In that case you lose your investment. A company scheme where you can lose more than your investment is rare. (However, If a limited company gives a director a loan instead of salary, which can be done to save/avoid taxes, that loan has to be repaid if the company goes bankrupt).